# Azure App Service returning bad gateway error 502

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I'm trying to deploy my project on azure app service. I've deployed several times but now suddenly I can't deploy and I am receiving **Error 502 bad gateway**. Also, I've tried to access Kudu to check the logs there but I've received the following error.

> There was an unexpected error in the request processing.

It seems kudu is stopped and I can't deploy anymore. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, what is the solution for this?